# Can I be sure than a const reference is updated when modified by another entity?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, pass-by-reference, const-correctness

I have a class `Foo` having the rights to read an instance of class `Bar`, but doesn't have the rights to modify it. In the same time, the instance of `Bar` could be modified by other elements.

For the moment, I implement it by this way:

```
class Foo
{
  private:
    const Bar& bar; // Foo can't modify it
  public:
    Foo(const Bar& bar_) : bar(bar_) {}
    void doSomthing() { this->bar.printData(); }
};
```

And it could be used like this:

```
Bar bar;
Foo foo(bar);
bar.update(); // This modify the instance of Bar
foo.doSomthing(); // This use the reference to (modified) bar
```

My question is: **With this implementation, can I be sure than the compiler doesn't use a non updated copy of `bar` even if the reference is declared as `const` ?**

If no, how can I do that ?

*Note: I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason*

Comment: Short answer yes. Your code is fine and works as you expect.

Comment: I would expect any sane compiler to produce the correct code here. Out of curiosity, where does your doubt stem from?

Comment: @StoryTeller: because if I said to the compiler that somthing is constant, it could be logical that the compiler decide to create a copy in a closer memory than RAM (like the cache of the processor) whithout having to check if it was updated.

Comment: But you didn't tell it that. The object is not declared const.

Comment: @StoryTeller: right. But I was not sure. I don't master all the complexity of `const` and `mutable` aspects.

Comment: Well, I guess that's why [tag:d] has also an `immutable` keyword to differentiate these cases.

Comment: @Caduchon Here, `const` means logically const, not physically const. The compiler has no way to know what logically const means, so it can't make any assumptions. For example, a logically-const object might count how many times it is compared. That doesn't change its logical value. There is no safe assumption the compiler can make about logically-const objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can be sure. References are internally implemented in the compiler as pointers, and both `bar.update();` and `Foo::bar` are acting on the same memory location.

That's, of course, as long as there are no data race concerns, at which point the usual problems of synchronization arise.

Answer (score -1):

The best pre c++11 standard text I could find quickly was [this draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) from 2005, wich should be close enough to C++03.

It says in  3.10:13  [basic.lval]

> The referent of a const-qualified expression shall not be modified (**through that expression**), except that if it is of class type and has a mutable component, that component can be modified.

The emphasis is mine and highlights that it is to be expected that the referent **can** be modified though other expressions (if they themselves allow it).